# Testing a distributed application on a single system

Tags: java, virtual-machine, virtualbox, p2p, distributed-computing

I am writing a simple p2p application using Java 7 and [tomp2p](http://tomp2p.net/). The problem is that peers need to bootstrap to other peers in the same network and in order for that to work, the ports have to be set correctly and the broadcast messages need to be sent and received properly.

I would like to know the best setup for testing the application (or any distributed application) using a single machine (since I do not always have multiple machines to experiment with).

First, I simply tried running two instances of my application in different terminals (and this worked), but as soon as I tested it in a real network with two machines, the peers of my network were not able to find each other anymore.

Therefore, I am now running Ubuntu 12.04 as a host OS and a virtual machine ([virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) with a Fedora 17 image. However, for my application to work, the host and the VM need to appear as if they were in the same network, but somehow I could not figure out the right setup for this to work (this is due to some NAT issues).

Does anybody have experience with testing a distributed application on a single system, and can give me some hints about the setup and the virtual machines used?

Thanks in advance,

r0f1

Comment: You need to setup virtualbox with a "host-only private network" and add a nat one (2 adapters) if you need internet access from the VM

Comment: Thank you that helped ;) Also [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=46198) was useful for configuring virtualbox.

Comment: There is some configuration issue with the ports I can't figure out, I tried the following two things using netcat: 
1) Running "nc -l -p 6666 -v" on Ubuntu (the host) and running "nc -l -p 6666 -v" on Fedora (the vm). This worked, and I could exchange chat messages.
2) Running "nc -l 6666 -v" on Fedora and "nc 192.168.56.101 6666" on Ubuntu returned the following error message on Ubuntu "(UNKNOWN) [192.168.56.101] 6666 (?) : No route to host".
Why is it working one way but not the other?

Comment: Sorry, for 1) I meant to write "nc 192.168.56.1 6666" on Fedora.

Comment: Ok, I found the soulution: [here](http://superuser.com/a/533299)